# grok filter for processing log4j logs pattern in Logstash

Tags: log4j, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am stuck in finding  grok filter for processing  conversion pattern  `%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t][%c] %m%n` in log4j logs

here is an example log entry:

```
2018-02-12 12:10:03 INFO classname:25 - Exiting application.
2017-12-31 05:09:06 WARN foo:133 - Redirect Request : login
2015-08-19 08:07:03 INFO  DBConfiguration:47 - Initiating DynamoDb Configuration...
2016-02-12 11:06:49 ERROR foo:224 - Error Code : 500
```

can anyone help in finding the Logstash grok filter.

Comment: Your question is bad. Show what you've done, what doesn't work, what's the expected result and enough examples to easily reproduce your issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: For grok, you can use http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match to test your pattern and https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns to build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found the filter for your log4j pattren.

```
filter{
   mutate {
      gsub => ['message', "\n", " "]
          }

   grok { 
      match => { "message" => "(?<date>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) (?:%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}) +(?:%{WORD:caller_class}):(?:%{NONNEGINT:caller_line}) - (?:%{GREEDYDATA:msg})" } 
        }
     }
```

However, this is specific to the above log.